# Windows 10 Hyper-v Ubuntu install did not start

Tags: ubuntu, installation, hyper-v

I just switched to windows 10 from 8.1.
I tried to create an ubuntu vm gen2 x64(15.10, 14.04), but the installation won't start.
Honestly I have no idea whats the problem.
I created like 10-15 ubuntu vm in my life never see anything like this.
[image: Ubuntu Installation error]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 10 Home, note that it doesn't have hyper-v. For example the Android Studio emulator won't work.

[Check this question in superuser.](https://superuser.com/questions/948086/does-windows-10-home-includes-hyper-v)

[And this specification.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility)

Comment: I have windows 10 pro, already made a windows vm on my windows. Something really broken here I just tried arch linux, but I don't have keyboard on the vm.